# How to preselect in multiselect box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to preselect of id (195,197,120) by code on load
in multiselect box

coresponding id 195,197,120 will preselected

```
<select class="width100" id="dialog_settings_event_selected_recipient" style="height:80px;" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="120">Aaban bilal</option>
    <option value="197">Aabid iqbal</option>
    <option value="196">Aadan parvaiz shah</option>
    <option value="262">Aadil bashir</option>
    <option value="195">Aaksa iqbol</option>
    <option value="233">Aamir shabir</option>
    <option value="231">Aasma zahoor</option>
    <option value="198">Aathir shah bhat</option>
    <option value="208">Aatif dar</option>
    <option value="244">Aatif manzoor</option>
    <option value="77">Abrar Mushtaq</option>
    <option value="68">Adnan Javid</option>
    <option value="236">Adnan amin</option>
    <option value="132">Adnan iqbal</option>
    <option value="112">Adnan mushtaq pir</option>
    <option value="252">Adnan nazir-107</option>
    <option value="157">Afhan Mudasir</option>
    <option value="154">Ahsan Yousuf</option>
    <option value="87">Aijaz Ah Malik</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: simply add `selected` to the options you want to be selected :) `<option value="208" selected>Aatif dar</option>`, `<option value="132" selected>Adnan iqbal</option>`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set values for multiple select

```js
var data="120,197,195";

//Make an array

var dataarray=data.split(",");

// Set the value

$("#dialog_settings_event_selected_recipient").val(dataarray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="width100" id="dialog_settings_event_selected_recipient" style="height:80px;" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="120">Aaban bilal</option>
    <option value="197">Aabid iqbal</option>
    <option value="196">Aadan parvaiz shah</option>
    <option value="262">Aadil bashir</option>
    <option value="195">Aaksa iqbol</option>
    <option value="233">Aamir shabir</option>
    <option value="231">Aasma zahoor</option>
    <option value="198">Aathir shah bhat</option>
    <option value="208">Aatif dar</option>
    <option value="244">Aatif manzoor</option>
    <option value="77">Abrar Mushtaq</option>
    <option value="68">Adnan Javid</option>
    <option value="236">Adnan amin</option>
    <option value="132">Adnan iqbal</option>
    <option value="112">Adnan mushtaq pir</option>
    <option value="252">Adnan nazir-107</option>
    <option value="157">Afhan Mudasir</option>
    <option value="154">Ahsan Yousuf</option>
    <option value="87">Aijaz Ah Malik</option>
</select>
```